# Pandas: groupby multiple columns for bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV of financial data that is listed by:

1. Date
2. Category
3. Amount

The dataset looks like the following, with another hundred rows.  I am trying to use pandas to graph this data by month and then the total by each category.  An example would be a bar graph of each month (Jan - Dec) with a bar for the total of each Category type (Food & Drink, Shopping, Gas).

```
    Date                Category                Amount
0   12/29/2022          Food & Drink            -28.35  
1   12/30/2022          Shopping                -12.12  
2   11/30/2022          Food & Drink            -12.30  
3   11/30/2022          gas                     -12.31  
4   10/30/2022          Food & Drink            -6.98
....
```

My initial code worked, but totaled everything in the month and didn't separate by category type.

`df['Transaction Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y') df = df.groupby(df['Transaction Date'].dt.month)['Amount'].sum()`

[image]

My next try to separate the monthly information out by Category failed.

`df = df.groupby((df['Transaction Date'].dt.month),['Category'])['Amount'].sum()`

How can I graph out each month by the sum of Category type?

Here is an example. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column for months within the data frame and then groupby months and category columns

```py
df['Months'] = df['Transaction Date'].dt.month_name()
df = df.groupby(['Months', 'Category']).agg({'Amount':'sum'})
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is really helpful.  I have been trying a few combinations.  I believe this would work.  Then I can use the bar graph and run the x = 'Months'?  `df.plot(kind='bar', x='Months')`

Comment: No problem. You would need to give the category column as well. I would suggest seaborn (sns) bar plot which uses a parameter called "hue" to consider a third axis/ variable as well. For-example: sns.barplot(x='Months', y='Amount', data=df, hue='Category')